# Problems visualizing a description

Tags: vocabulary

I am currently learning Japanese and for the Chinese characters, there is a really nice book that combines stories or images to each character. The problem is that sometimes the description is a bit difficult for a non native English speaker (I wasn't sure though where to ask this question, here or in the English learners stack). The Character is the following:

[image]

And I cite the description from the book:

> This character is sort of a nickname for the Japanese flag with its
> well-known emblem of the rising sun. If you can picture two seams
> running down that great red sun, and then imagine it sitting on a
> baseball bat for a flagpole, you have a slightly irreverent-but not
> altogether inaccurate-picture of how the sport has caught on in the
> Land of the Rising Sun.

Can you picture this scene? And if yes, rephrase it in a simpler way?

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, and I can't really visualise that scene, or see in the slightest what it has to do with that kanji.

Comment: Writing advice & rewriting a passage for you are off-topic here.  Try Writers.SE instead.  Also off-topic because there are either too many possible answers, and/or it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: What book is it? I'm starting Japanese too.

Comment: I can read Japanese and Chinese characters (not all of them). I find the description worthless and unhelpful to learners. The left part represents how it sounds and the right part represents what it means. The right part means the "sun" and that's why the character is related with the "sun".

Comment: I don't think you have given full context, but what I do understand from it is that if you imagine the rectangular part as a baseball and the main verticals of the other part as a baseball bat, the whole can be seen as an image of the national flag represented through baseball imagery: hence the whole becomes a symbol of the popularity of baseball in Japan. It seems to be a combination of word play with image play.

Comment: @vickyace the books is called "Remembering the Kanji".

Comment: @Rathony it might seem like that for people who already memorized the kanjis with some understanding, but the Amazon reviews are quite positive. In my case I could learn the writing of 15 Kanjis a day (just the writing though, no reading yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This character is sort of a nickname for the Japanese flag (旭日旗/きょくじつはた） with its well-known symbol of the rising sun. If you can picture red stripes coming out of a great red sun, and then imagine the flag sitting on a baseball **hat** **or** a flagpole, you might have a slightly disrespectful, but a vivid mental picture of how the sport has become popular in the Land of the Rising Sun.

[image: Baseball hat]
[image: 旭日旗/きょくじつはた]

In Chinese and Japanese culture, when something is popular, we can say it's like a sun shining in the sky. However, 旭 particularly means the sun is rising.

Comment: I think  now I will never forget this character with all those picture :D, thanks